# Customer params in kubectl when run docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want the command like follows:

```
   docker run -d --net=host
```

How can I pass the --net=host params to the docker through kubectl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "hostNetwork" field to true in the pod spec to enable host networking. See the [kube-apiserver manifest](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.1.2/cluster/saltbase/salt/kube-apiserver/kube-apiserver.manifest#L108) for an example.

Comment: It seems the hostNetwork just means  the controller and scheduler are listening on 127.0.0.1? Is I'm misunderstood?  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/14163

Comment: In the case of those binaries, they bind to 127.0.0.1. If you use host networking, you can also bind to any network address that is on the host.

Comment: So if I set hostNetwork: true, does it means I run the docker in the --net=host?

Comment: Yes, `hostNetwork: true` starts the docker container with the `--net=host` flag.